# Browser re-sizing changes the position of <nav> elements

Tags: html, css

[image: Perfect Look!]

This is what my webpage looks like. But when I re-size my browser, the  elements changes the position and moves with vertical scrollbar! How to make them fixed at the top?

[image]

My html5 code:

```
<header id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a id="index" href="index.html"><img src="img/LOGO.PNG" alt="Scope in CST" /></a>
        </div>

        <nav id="menu">
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="events.html">Events</a>
            <li id="smenu"><a href="#">Communities</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ambassadors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Idea</a></li>
            </ul></li>
            <a href="#">Angel Investors</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a>
            <Button type="button" onClick="location.href='memebrs.scopecst.org';">Login</Button>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is what I've done in the css so far:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give a demo link? its useful to solve your question!!

Comment: I can't upload the whole code, I've provided the coding for nav and its corresponding css. If you can help me using the same.

Comment: Well the reason why this happens is because it seems as though there is too much whitespace, and it causes the element to overflow. You could try decreasing margin/padding

Answer (score 0):

When you resize your browser, you are changing the width of the entire screen, therefore the menu stops fitting. Also, it will not be in the nav because you have a set height on the nav so the nav stays the same size, while your login button pops out of the line-up. The login button jumps down because (looking closely at the code) you have `margin-left: 150px;` therefore the login button must always be 150px away from the left. A potential fix (although it isn't the most ideal fix) is to use `float: right;` for the login button instead. That should allow it to slide closer to the `<nav>` menu when you resize the page.